Jenkins unable to access key file. I keep getting permission "denied" when trying to run jenkins build
Task is to provision an instance with terraform and install tomcat with ansible using a jenkins job. I've been able to this on the server using terraform apply. When i try to do it on Jenkins it fails and on looking at the output when it gives permission denied when trying to access the file path where the key is. I need a solution or someone who has experienced similar because I've tried a lot of things. whoami is tomcat, because Jenkins is running on tomcat. Jenkins output
top of terraform main.tf file
ive tried changing file permission, adding tomcat to wheel group, root group, adding tomcat to sudoers NO:PASSWD. Still gives permission denied

you have to run it under user jenkins. That would entail installing jenkins on th server not through a tomcat container. jenkins user workspace is under /var/lib/jenkins. Just chown (change ownership) of the working directory and group to jenkins while being root user.
